# Volley restart cancelled requests

Tags: android, android-volley, request-cancelling

I use a singleton `RequestQueue` to queue Volley requests. I have added a cancel method in `onStop` of my activity which stops the request. But when I add the cancelled request to the queue for retry it does not work. Here is the code:

My activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int requestId;
    protected Request previousRequest;
    private RequestQueueSingleton requestQueueSingleton;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(previousRequest != null && previousRequest.isCancelled) {
            requestQueueSingleton.add(previousRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        requestQueueSingleton.cancelRequests(requestId);
    }
}
```

Request singleton:

```
public class RequestQueueSingleton {

    private static RequestQueueSingleton instance;

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public static RequestQueueSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RequestQueueSingleton(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private RequestQueueSingleton(Context context) {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
     }

    public void addToQueue(Request request) {
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public void cancelRequests(int tag) {
        requestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }

}
```

Note that everything is working accordingly, no crashes occur. Its just when the app goes to the background and comes back the response is not delivered. Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you making `RequestQueueSingleton` singleton?? Normally, I make my singleton `static`, I have never seen any singleton without `static`.

Comment: This is actually the activity class. I have the singleton in a different class.

Comment: Yes, that will suffice. Because according to me your variable is not singleton  by just observing this part of code. And main problem will be because of non-singleton variable

Comment: Post your RequestQueueSingleton code & entire class of above snippet

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake, Always use `RequestQueueSingleton. getInstance(context)` where ever you want. else no use

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake, I have edited the answer, check it back

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(context).cancelRequests(requestId);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Use cancel all request before calling `super.onPause();`

Check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState
for my support of the answer.

Comment: I tried this but no luck. My request gets cancelled correctly, the problem is retrying when `onStart` gets called.

Comment: Oh I read it wrong. I thought it's not cancelling. You will need to save previous request in `onSaveInstanceState()` and retrieve that request in `onRestoreInstanceState()`